# Getting data from an image with astropy?

Tags: python, matplotlib, astropy

So I've imported a FITS file and shown an image using astropy and matplotlib. This image has some bright spots but i can't figure out how to highlight specific bright areas of interest on the image and get a mean value of brightness. can anyone help?

Comment: Hello, as asked this question may be a little "too broad" for Stack Overflow, as it's not necessarily asking a specific programming question, and to even begin answer to your question depends a bit on domain-specific (astronomy) knowledge as well as more details about your data and what it looks like.  However, it's possible packages like [photutils](https://photutils.readthedocs.io/en/stable/detection.html) could be useful to you, or maybe one of the other [Astropy affiliated packages](https://www.astropy.org/affiliated/index.html) such as [imexam](https://imexam.readthedocs.io/)

Answer (score 0):

Example:

```py
from astropy.io import fits
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

## Read
hdul = fits.open('yourfile.fits')
image = hdul[0].data
Ny, Nx = image.shape

## Mean (careful if the unit is MJy/sr)
avg = np.nanmean(image)
print('Image mean = ', avg)

## Plot (mark bright spots)
xl = []
yl = []
for x in range(Nx):
    for y in range(Ny):
        if image[y,x]>avg:
            xl.append(x)
            yl.append(y)
plt.imshow(image)
plt.scatter(xl, yl, c='r', marker='o')
plt.show()
```